# How to integrate google plus Oauth API in Phonegap for android app

Tags: cordova, oauth, google-plus

I want to do authentication of my Phonegap Android application using google plus. I have used Oauth Google API. I have used client ID and client secret from google plus Oauth API but i don't know what to write in Redirection URI. What to write in Redirection URI ? i have used this http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html for making my Phonegap app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice question 
i had also same issue
and resolved it by

use "**localhost**" as Redirection uri.
i hope helps you.