# Phonegap: Converting websites on localhost to app

Tags: cordova, google-plus, dreamweaver

I just created a website with Dreamweaver CS6, deployed on localhost. I want to convert it to a mobile app with the Phonegap build-in from Dreamweaver. I got the layout converted, but the Google+ login features are not working as the website. I figure it may have something to do with my google API client key been set to localhost. So if I want to run as an app, what type of client key should I get from Google? Web application, localhost or mobile app? Or am I missing something else here?

Just a part of my website code:

```
function login()
{
  var myParams = {
    'clientid' : '699473XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',    //How should I change this?
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'loginCallback', 
    'approvalprompt':'force',
    'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
  };
  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
```

}

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703227/how-to-integrate-google-plus-oauth-api-in-phonegap-for-android-app ?

Comment: Yes, I've looked into that. I've changed my client key to android application but still it doesn't work? Are there other things I have to change myself before letting Phonegap does the job for me to convert my website into a mobile app?